# Which version of docker/moby best match with kubernetes 1.9.7?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, production-environment, moby

In production, Which version of docker/moby best match with kubernetes 1.9.7 in best practice?

I use kubernetes 1.9.7 and docker 1.12.6, there are some errors:

```
"/tmp/docker -c /tmp/k.conf " process use 100% CPU

top - 09:33:31 up 18:02,  2 users,  load average: 9.59, 9.13, 6.96
Tasks: 211 total,   2 running, 209 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 79.8 us, 20.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8043956 total,  2832356 free,  2356916 used,  2854684 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  5308876 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                  
25540 root      20   0  406464  11284   1492 S 152.5  0.1  21:55.30 /tmp/docker -c /tmp/k.conf                               
25029 root      20   0  406464  12680   1364 S 143.2  0.2  26:28.79 /tmp/docker -c /tmp/k.conf                               
23265 dockeri+  20   0    1992    108     64 R  98.3  0.0  24:58.45 40f4huf4nhf4jpqm mp/k.conf
```

Comment: (1) why are you using an ancient version of kubernetes? (2) what is `/tmp/docker`? (3) it has been my experience that a load average _that high_ is almost always I/O, and not just CPU; it could be swap usage, too, as a special case of the I/O bottleneck

Comment: There is a bug filed with the same issue https://forums.docker.com/t/tmp-docker-c-tmp-k-conf-process-use-more-than-100-cpu/51696/2 but IMO this is a some malicious process rather than docker itself

Comment: it seems like a "Trojan viruses" called “Mirai” family, We are woking for it....

Answer (score 1):

> The validated docker versions are the same as for v1.8: 1.11.2 to 1.13.1 and 17.03.x

See [changelog-1.9](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.9.md#external-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

It's a "Trojan viruses" or "Miner" in “Mirai” family, You may be needed to  reinstall your OS.